# sharing Png image as a file in android application

Tags: java, android, image, png

using this function I try to share PNG file. But when it makes a PNG file and I share it through for example whatsUp application,  it changes it to jpg and make its background black. how can I share it in way that its transparency be saved? I try to remove the extension of file from

```
  newFile = new File(cachePath, "image.png");
```

to

```
  newFile = new File(cachePath, "image");
```

in this way its transparency is preserved. I send it whatsup and I can download it to pc and then change its extension to PNG again.
is there any other way?

```
public void shareImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
                
          File f = new File(new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
             "image.jpeg");
    f.mkdir();
    
    
    
        try {
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    
            out.flush();
            out.close();
    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
      //  Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "activity.yyy.xxx.provider", newFile);
             Uri contentUri=    Uri.parse(f.getPath());

        if (contentUri != null) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
            shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose"));
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

stacktrace:

```
 W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/activity.yyy.xxx/app_nn_images/image.jpeg: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at activity.yyy.xxx.EditImageActivity.shareImage(EditImageActivity.java:1389)
        at activity.yyy.xxx.EditImageActivity$buttonClickAsync.doInBackground(EditImageActivity.java:1351)
        at activity.yyy.xxx.EditImageActivity$buttonClickAsync.doInBackground(EditImageActivity.java:1332)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:252)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:167)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7490)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:482)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem I did this in the following way and I saved the copy of Image by creating an internal folder in the package as follows

```
FileOutputStream fos;
                    // Create imageDir
                    String FILENAME = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()) + ".jpeg";
                    File f = new File(new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), FILENAME);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddProductActivity.this, "Field should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                    }
                    fos.close();
```

In this way to create Uri you can use `Uri.parse(f.getPath())`.
In this way, I didn't face any issues.
Extra tip: Using Glide will help to load images relatively faster.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

Just add this into your Gradle (Module Level)

Comment: I change the code and also change Uri.Parse. but it gives me the error:  file is not suported

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error

Comment: I add it to question

Comment: The issue is arising because the folder name and the image name are the same. I am not having issues with this because when I am making a copy of an image and saving it I am making its name as a timestamp, not with the same name.
`String FILENAME = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()) + ".jpeg";` Here I am creating timestamp in the above code.

Comment: no, I change file name to timestamp as you said and there is same error again

Comment: I am sending you the changes to do and try
`File f = new File(new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
             "image.jpeg");` to `File f = new File(new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).getDir("images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),
             "image.png");` as you are working with png and also remove `f.mkdir();`
Moreover, I am attaching the link for how I've passed the message and image to other apps
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMx0naOcEz5A4TUMX6uPhwBignGAgKRi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240709/discussion-between-ghazanfar-ateeb-and-saeedeh).